# Cannot connect Nginx with uwsgi +Django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

What I've tried:
1. Nginx is fine, can access 80 port and see the default page
2. uwsgi + django is fine, I can use uwsgi to start my django app and access it
,with command:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module webapps.wsgi
```

the problem come out when I connect uwsgi to nginx

```
2017/11/07 01:36:47 [error] 27958#27958: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.61.176.181, server: 104.196.31.159, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "104.196.31.159:8000"
```

here is the mysite.conf for nginx

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///home/liuziqicmu/ziqil1/homework/6/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx(my ip); # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/liuziqicmu/ziqil1/homework6/grumblr/upload;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/liuziqicmu/ziqil1/homework6/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/liuziqicmu/ziqil1/homework/6/env/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

the command I start it :

```
uwsgi --socket 8001 --module webapps.wsgi
```

also , when I run nginx -t, it shows:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/11/07 02:02:13 [warn] 19350#19350: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2017/11/07 02:02:13 [emerg] 19350#19350: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `/var/log/nginx` and `/run` exist and can be written by nginx

Comment: I fixed the problem by copy mysite.conf to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ .       previously I just ln -s to that path, but could anyone tell me why soft link doesn't work?